# Unmarshalling saml metadata extensions using opensaml

Tags: metadata, saml-2.0, opensaml

I have created some extensions in saml metadata. I'm trying to unmarshall the xml using opensaml2. I have created the interface, implementation class, builder, marshaller and unmarshaller of the extension. Then I registered the object providers using Configuration.registerObjectProvider

```
Configuration.registerObjectProvider(RequestedAudiences.TYPE_NAME, new RequestedAudiencesBuilder(), new RequestedAudiencesMarshaller(), new RequestedAudiencesUnmarshaller());
```

When I try to get the extensions using the bellow code segment

```
List<XMLObject> extensions = spssoDescriptor.getExtensions().getUnknownXMLObjects();
```

It returns objects of the type

```
org.opensaml.xml.schema.impl.XSAnyImpl
```

So now I can't read any value from the object. I want to get an object of the actual extension implementation class I have created.
Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I have registered the object providers after creating the metadata object. So at the time of creating the metadata object, opensaml does not know how to create the required extension object (RequestedAudiences object). Registering the object providers before creating the metadata object resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below `scala` code to extract the information.

```
val dato = descriptor.getExtensions().getUnknownXMLObjects.get(0).asInstanceOf[XSAny]
println(dato.getTextContent)
```